# Default values in model property based on another property in the same model django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I want to send default values based on another key in the same model and I'm using Django with Postgres, for example, if the `type = 'owner' || 'admin'` so the `can_edit` property should be `true` otherwise it should be `false`.

models.py

```py
class Type(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Role(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   can_edit = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

serializers.py

```py
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'type', 'can_edit']
```

views.py

```py
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def roles_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        role = RoleSerializer(data=request.data)
        role.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        role.save()
        return Response({'data': role.data, 'success': True})
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I set `can_edit` based on `type.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the save method on 'Role' class in models.py
Add this in models.py under class Role

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.type.name == 'owner' or self.type.name == 'admin':
            self.can_edit = True
        super(Role, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to set 'can_edit' to False otherwise then edit the line

```
can_edit = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

to

```
can_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: `self.type` is a foreign key relation would it get the name in `self.type`?

Comment: Yes, when accessed using self.type.name. See the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example pre_save signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Role)
def validate_can_edit(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if instance.type.name == 'admin':
        can_edit = True
```

But I want to suggest different solution.
Move can_edit flag to Type model like this:

```
class Type(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   can_edit = models.BooleanField(null=True)


class Role(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This way you can access `can_edit` flag using `type.can_edit` AND you will not lose this functionality when renaming Type to different name like from `admin` to `Admin`

Comment: can you share an example according to my case?

Answer (score 0):

like Bartosz Stasiak said. You can use a pre_save signal which is called before saving the data to the database.

First, create a new signals.py file in your directory.

write as follows:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .app import Role #import your model here

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Role) # in sender you have to put the model where the pre_save function is called
def validate_can_edit(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if instance.type.casefold() in ['owner', 'admin']:  #checking if values are equal and convert the input value to lowercase to avoid case-sensitive issues.
        instance.can_edit = True
     else:
        instance.can_edit = False
```

in your serializers.py remove **can_edit** field as you won't need it anymore and will be assigned by the signal function before saving to database.

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'type']
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I've added a `print` statement in my `validate_can_edit` function but I think the function was not invoked, or maybe something else was wrong there